# How to speed up clearcase static view update?

Tags: windows, clearcase

I have a clearcase static view with many vobs. Unfortunately I cannot use dynamic view. The total amount of data is about 40 Gb. Sometimes I need to update view from command line with minor changes in the vobs. However, even if I update the view when, for example, **single** file version only should be updated this way

```
cleartool.exe setcs -overwrite config_spec.txt
```

it takes really long time (more than hour). What can be done to speed up static view update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `setcs` will trigger a *full* view update.

If you have only one file whose version should change because of the config spec, you simply can [`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) that specific file:

```
 cleartool update -overwrite /path/to/file
```

You only do a `setcs` if the config spec itself has changed (i.e. if one of the selection rule changes).

> For one or more loaded elements, the update command does the following:
>
> - Reevaluates the config spec to select versions of loaded elements in the VOB and loads them if they differ from the currently loaded versions
> - Unloads the file or directory from the view if a loaded element is no longer visible (that is, a new directory version does not have an entry for the element).
> - Copies the version selected by the config spec into the snapshot view, if the version in the view is different from the version in the VOB selected by the config spec.